# How to user "Where" in "Include" and "Select" query in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

In my database, I have `3` tables, `Exams`, `ExamPlaces`, `Agents`. The Id of each exam in the **Exams** table is a foreign key in the **ExamPlaces** table and the Id of each Exam Place is a foreign key in the **Agents** table. I want to return all exams from a specific Agent. I tried to return the exams like this:

```
return _db.Exams
            .Include(e => e.ExamPlaces.Select(a => a.Agents
                .Where(agent => agent.AgentId == supervisorId))).ToList();
```

But I got the below error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path

Is it possible to use "`Where`" clause like how I did with "`Include`" to retrieved data?

Appreciate

Comment: do your filtering in a where outside of the include.

Comment: In an include, you can only specify to load a Navigation property (to materialize something stored in a different table). For you probably (e => e.ExamlPlaces).
You cannot filter to do it "sometimes". it's not possible to get a list of Exams, with Agents sometimes loaded, sometimes not. It's always or never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, EF 6 doesn't support to filter in the `Include` method.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ [Query IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter) (free and open source) allows easily filter included entities.

To use it, you simply need to replace all "Include" by "IncludeFilter". You also at this moment need to use IncludeFilter on every level.

Example:

```
return _db.Exams
            .IncludeFilter(e => e.ExamPlaces)
            .IncludeFilter(e => e.ExamPlaces.Select(a => a.Agents
                .Where(agent => agent.AgentId == supervisorId))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Include doesn't affect which records get returned. It enables eager loading of the navigation properties specified. Essentially, it's a way of saying, "Yes, I want some Exams, but I'll also use the corresponding ExamPlaces later on, so go ahead and get them from the database now to save time". It has nothing to do with the Where.

In this particular case, Where is difficult to work with. That has nothing to do with Include. If you really want to start with _db.Exams and use Where, I think you could put a Join somewhere before the Where to get it working.

However, think of the query the other way around. You already have the agent you want. That agent has a collection of ExamPlaces, and the ExamPlaces each has a collection of Exams. You just need to flatten those out into a single list. Something like this should work (not checked for syntax errors):

```
return _db.Agents
        .Find(supervisorId)
        .ExamPlaces
        .SelectMany(p => p.Exams)
        .Include(e => e.ExamPlaces.Select(p => p.Agents))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Actually ExamPlaces table has a collection of Agents, and Exams has a collection of ExamPlaces. So in your code after .ExamPlaces I don't have SelectMany() option.

Comment: Ah. I missed that Agent has a foreign key into ExamPlace, so that's a one-to-many rather than a many-to-many relationship. That makes things a bit simpler.

Comment: Wait. Agent holds a foreign key that references ExamPlace, and ExamPlace holds a foreign key that references Exam? That would mean each Agent has one ExamPlace, which has one Exam. `_db.Agents.Find(supervisorId).ExamPlace.Exam` would return the *one* exam that corresponds to that agent.

Comment: Each ExamPlace holds foreign key from Exams and each Agent holds foreign Key from ExamPlaces.